# Facebook PHP: How to cast GraphNode to GraphEvent?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I get a response from API with a list of events:

```
$graphEdge = $response->getGraphEdge();
foreach ($graphEdge as $graphNode) {
    $graphNodes[] = $graphNode;
}
```

Each cell of $graphEdge is treated as a GraphNode, while it is a GraphEvent  (class GraphEvent extends GraphNode). How can I get the SDK to recognize objects properly?

Now I cannot use methods specific for GraphEvent like getPlace() or even getName(), because I get an error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Facebook\GraphNodes\GraphNode::getName()
```

Of course using getField('name') etc. work, but I'd like a prettier solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According the code, you can use `$response->getGraphEdge('GraphEvent')`.